# what are good mesh animation techniques?

Tags: c++, animation, mesh

I want to create a 2D game with monsters build as a custom vertex mesh and a texture map. I want to use this mesh to provide smooth vector animations. I'm using opengl es 2.0.

For now the best idea i have is to write a simple editor, where i can create a mesh and make key-frame based animation by changing position of each vertex and specifying the key-frames interpolation technics ( linear, quadric and so on).

I also have some understanding of bone animation (and skin based on bones), but i'm not sure i will be able to provide a good skeletons for my monsters.

I'm not sure it is a good way to go. Can you suggest some better ideas and / or editors, libraries for such mesh animations ?

PS: i'm using C++ now and so c++ libraries are the most welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said this is a 2D game, so I'm going to assume your characters are flat polygons on to which you apply a texture map. Please add more detail to your question if this is not the case.

As far as the C++ part I think the same principles used for 3D blend shape animation can be applied to this case. For each character you will have a list of possible 'morph targets' or poses, each being a different polygon shape with same number of vertices. The character's AI will determine when to change from one to another, and how long a transition takes. So at any given point time your character can be either at a fixed state, matching one of your morph targets, or it can be in a transition state between two poses. The first has no trouble, the second case is handled by interpolating the vertices of the two polygons one by one to arrive to a morphed polygon. You can start with linear interpolation and see if that is sufficient, I suspect you may want to at least apply an easing function to the start and end of the transitions, maybe the [smoothstep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep) function.

As far as authoring these characters, have you considered using [Blender](http://www.blender.org/)? You can design and test your characters entirely within this package, then export the meshes as .obj files that you can easily import into your game.

Comment: you mean i should create one .obj file per one pose?

Comment: Yes. All the .objs will have the same number of vertices, but they will be in a different position, matching the actions you want your character to perform. For each character you will then have an array of meshes, one per pose.